# How do I make macOS native Contacts the default application for adding a contact instead of Microsoft Outlook's Contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, office-for-mac

My Outlook Version is 16.14.1.

Elaboration:

- I'm in the native Messages client. Someone sends me a contact through
  iMessage.
- I add that contact through the UI in Messages.
- Expectation: the contact gets added to my native macOS Contacts.
  Reality: the contact gets added to my Outlook contacts.

I don't recall doing anything notable during install that made this happen.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough the Address Book.app has no GUI method of setting itself as the default handler for addresses, annoying.

There is a work around that may work for you. Drag **any** one contact out to the desktop. You will get a .vcf file. Get Info on that file (select it > File Menu > Get Info) and under the "Open With" section choose Contacts.app and then click on the "Change All" button and affirm your choice to make .vcf files open with the built-in address book app.

It's a bit of a kludge but should work for you.